# How to train Neural Network to predict SQRT of a number in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, sqrt

I want to train NN to predict `sqrt` of a number in `tensorflow`, and the following is my code, but the loss can not drop to 0, and the result is not correct, what is the problem?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dimension = 1
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dimension])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([dimension, 100], stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
    h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)

    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 50], stddev=0.01))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([50]))
    h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, W2) + b2)

    W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([50, 1], stddev=0.01))
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    y = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h2, W3) + b3)

    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dimension])

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y - Y, 2))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for epoch in range(1000):
            sx = np.random.rand(1000, 1)
            sy = np.sqrt(sx)
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "%.03f" % c)
        sx = np.random.rand(10000, 1)
        sy = np.sqrt(sx)
        tc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
        print("Testing cost=", tc)
        sx = np.array([[0.01], [0.5]])
        sy = np.sqrt(sx)
        print sy
        print sess.run(y, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
        print sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
```

And Here is the output, it can't get the right result:

```
...
('Epoch:', '0999', 'cost=', '0.502')
('Epoch:', '1000', 'cost=', '0.499')
('Testing cost=', 0.49828479)
[[ 0.1       ]
 [ 0.70710678]]
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
0.255
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things to understand I guess:

1.Avoid using RELU in last layer because it might make gradients to zero.

2.It's difficult for NN to extrapolate for all random values. Loss might decrease, but it doesn't give you correct results on new data.

3.You have to select a subset of data (I took integers in range [1,50])  and you can observe it trains and predicts properly for that subset but it doesn't extrapolate to others well.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dimension = 1
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dimension])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([dimension, 100], stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
    h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W) + b)

    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 50], stddev=0.01))
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([50]))
    h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, W2) + b2)

    W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([50, 1], stddev=0.01))
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    y = (tf.matmul(h2, W3) + b3)

    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, dimension])

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y,Y))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        cap = 50
        for epoch in range(2000):
            sx = np.random.randint(cap,size=(100, 1))
            #sx = np.random.rand(100,1)
            sy = np.sqrt(sx)
            op,c = sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
            if epoch % 100 == 0:
                print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "%.03f" % c)

        #sx = np.random.rand(10,1)
        sx = np.random.randint(cap,size=(10,1))
        sy = np.sqrt(sx)
        print "Input"
        print sx
        print "Expected Output"
        print sy
        print "Predicted Output"
        print sess.run(y, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
        print "Error"
        print sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: sx, Y: sy})
```

Output Logs :

```
('Epoch:', '0001', 'cost=', '25.258')
('Epoch:', '0101', 'cost=', '0.428')
('Epoch:', '0201', 'cost=', '0.452')
('Epoch:', '0301', 'cost=', '0.456')
('Epoch:', '0401', 'cost=', '0.320')
('Epoch:', '0501', 'cost=', '0.306')
('Epoch:', '0601', 'cost=', '0.312')
('Epoch:', '0701', 'cost=', '0.321')
('Epoch:', '0801', 'cost=', '0.268')
('Epoch:', '0901', 'cost=', '0.228')
('Epoch:', '1001', 'cost=', '0.264')
('Epoch:', '1101', 'cost=', '0.246')
('Epoch:', '1201', 'cost=', '0.241')
('Epoch:', '1301', 'cost=', '0.251')
('Epoch:', '1401', 'cost=', '0.141')
('Epoch:', '1501', 'cost=', '0.218')
('Epoch:', '1601', 'cost=', '0.213')
('Epoch:', '1701', 'cost=', '0.146')
('Epoch:', '1801', 'cost=', '0.186')
('Epoch:', '1901', 'cost=', '0.176')
Input
[[29]
 [39]
 [10]
 [ 2]
 [ 2]
 [17]
 [ 4]
 [26]
 [ 3]
 [31]]
Expected Output
[[ 5.38516481]
 [ 6.244998  ]
 [ 3.16227766]
 [ 1.41421356]
 [ 1.41421356]
 [ 4.12310563]
 [ 2.        ]
 [ 5.09901951]
 [ 1.73205081]
 [ 5.56776436]]
Predicted Output
[[ 5.11237049]
 [ 6.35184956]
 [ 2.75735927]
 [ 1.76557863]
 [ 1.76557863]
 [ 3.62499475]
 [ 2.01356125]
 [ 4.74052668]
 [ 1.88956988]
 [ 5.36026621]]
Error
0.0941391
```

Comment: @prime_tang, did this help you ?

Comment: So you basically edited OPs question the way you think appropriate. It is not still clear what you meant: "I want to train sqrt using NN". Try to explain to anyone doing machine learning what training square root using neural network mean.

Comment: Hi @SalvadorDali, I think, prime_tang wants to know, "can neural network be trained to calculate the square root of any number ? and how ? ". It is just like approximation of any other function (xor/xnor).

Comment: @SalvadorDali  1. https://www.quora.com/Can-a-neural-network-be-trained-to-calculate-the-square-root-of-a-number-up-to-a-certain-digit-How 2. https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/f5d940ba6cd11d4d7fd0

Comment: Ok, this "can neural network be trained to calculate the square root of any number" makes sense. If this is the case, then yes NN can approximate any function to any precision. But I would never thought that this is what the original question wanted

Comment: @SalvadorDali I just want to test the capabilities of the neural network while learning to use tensorflow.

Comment: @hars Thanks very much!

Comment: @prime_tang, please accept the answer so the question is closed.